# Can we use two MTProto connections in a single app?

Tags: telegram-bot, telethon

Hello I am trying to run both "userbot" and "bot account" in a single app (worker).

These two connections are namely `tbot[main bot]` and `ubot[userbot]`. For example:

```
tbot = TelegramClient("myapp", API_KEY, API_HASH)

tbot.start(bot_token=TOKEN)

ubot = TelegramClient(StringSession(STRING_SESSION), API_KEY, API_HASH)

ubot.start()
```

But the problem is these two connections can't run simultaneously, both the connections quits just after the first (`tbot`) starts

Anything I can do here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use python [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) for that

```py
import threading

# ...

tbot = TelegramClient("myapp", API_KEY, API_HASH)

tbot_thread = threading.Thread(target=tbot.start, kwargs={'bot_token': TOKEN})
tbot_thread.start()

ubot = TelegramClient(StringSession(STRING_SESSION), API_KEY, API_HASH)

ubot_thread = threading.Thread(target=ubot.start)
ubot_thread.start()
```

So each client will start separately in separate Thread instead of waiting in the main thread. If anything else fails - see logs.